# Почему следующая программа выводит 1?

Tags: c

```
main(_)
{
    printf("%d",_);
}

 gcc -o test.c test
```

> test.exe
>
> 1

Comment: А что означает _? 

У меня пишет 

error C2065: _: необъявленный идентификатор

Если только не сделать вот так вот:

#define _ 1

Comment: а я почем знаю, что оно означает? у меня все компилится без ошибок, код програмы как есть

Comment: @manking: v в старых версиях C (K&R?) аргумент без типа считался по умолчанию `int`'ом.

Comment: Да, но почему он принимает символ подчеркивания, без типа? Почему он принимает main без указания типа возвращаемого аргумента?

Comment: тип возвращаемого значения по умолчанию вполне может быть `int` тоже.

Comment: А что насчет >_ ?

Comment: @SoloMio: _ — это имя аргумента, его тип в старых компиляторах по унмолчанию `int` же!

Comment: А в чём смысл такого аргумента по умолчанию? Экономит размер исходника?

Comment: @manking: Мне кажется, во времена Кернигана и Ричи смысл был, потому что _большинство_ переменных были просто целыми числами. С тех времён круг типичных задач поменялся, и язык C поменялся в соответствии с этим.

Comment: Отличный вопрос!

Comment: Ну мне кажется для невидимых компьютеров, это еще актуально.
Например какой размер ОЗУ и ПЗУ у устройства колки льда в холодильниках?

http://www.euromaxx.ru/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/bosch-kan-58a45ru.jpg

Comment: @manking: а фиг его знает, но мой телефон на пару порядков мощнее чем та техника, на которой американцы обсчитывали свой первый космический запуск.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Из [стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (§ 5.1.2.2.1) следует, что так писать функцию `main` нельзя, и результат зависит от конкретной имплементации:

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
> prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
> parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
> used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Предположу, что в вашем случае:

1. Бестиповый аргумент посчитался `int`'ом, как в старых версиях C. То же относится к возвращаемому значению функции.
2. `argc` отобразился на эту переменную (если вы запускаете программу без аргументов, `argc == 1`).

Можно проверить эту версию, передав в программу аргументы командной строки и проверив, как поменяется вывод программы.

Чтобы компилятор переключился на более современный диалект языка, попробуйте ключ `-std=c99`.

Comment: Чудесно. Но, как в анекдоте про съехавшую на колено повязку: "как же она съехала?". Почему на `_` нет ругани, что она не объявлена. А если заменить `_` на `a` -- сразу получим ошибку.

Comment: @alexlz: УМВР: http://pastebin.com/Upu9q3kP

Comment: @VladD Не знаю, кто такая УМВР, но глаз у меня точно замылился. параметр у main он упорно не замечал. Сорри.

Comment: @alexlz: УМВР = "У Меня Всё Работает", стандартная отмазка ленивого программиста.